# Redirect audio output to input stream - python-sounddevice

Tags: python, winapi, audio, portaudio, python-sounddevice

I'm using the [sounddevice](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.1/) library for Python. So far I was able to do some basic stuff with audio files through this library, like playing back a WAV format file using this code from one of the tutorials:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf

try:
    data, fs = sf.read('[path to audio file]', dtype='float32')
    sd.play(data, fs, device=None)
    status = sd.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Keyboard interrupt")
except Exception as e:
    print("Internal exception")
```

However, I need to redirect that audio output to the system's microphone input instead of the speakers, and I'm not sure how to do that with this library since there isn't a lot of clear documentation on this. Is there a way to do this with sounddevice? I would like to avoid directly interacting with the OS sound drivers, since ideally this should be cross-platform.

Thanks!

Edit: It seems like it's not possible to make this fully cross-platform, so ideally I would like to be able to use this with Windows and the WSAPI.

Comment: There is no cross-platform way to do this.

Comment: @Matthias OK, I understand. Is there a way to do this in Windows specifically then?

Comment: If there's no existing code for this online, you probably would have to do it all from scratch. I don't think that's in the scope of a StackOverflow question.

Comment: @javathunderman I don't know about Windows. But you can search for "virtual audio cable", "loopback device" or something like that. It's really independent from whatever Python library you use, this happens at a lower level. Once you have your virtual loopback cable, it will appear in the device list of the `sounddevice` module.

Comment: You could see this WSAPI document: [Loopback Recording](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/loopback-recording)

Comment: @Matthias @ Drake Wu - MSFT OK, thanks for your help. I'll look into these options.

Answer (score 0):

My original reason for asking this question was to create a cross-platform soundboard, and I've since discovered that [Soundux](https://github.com/Soundux/Soundux) works well for this use case.